# Android: App crashes in release mode with signed certificate

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

The app is working fine in debug mode but crashing when releasing the APK with a signed certificate. Can someone please help me? I am unable to understand this error message.

Here are the Error logs:

```
2020-07-30 18:21:36.143 26971-26971/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.nobleoil.taginstallationapp, PID: 26971
    java.lang.NullPointerException: throw with null exception
        at c.c.a.b.f.b(:7)
        at f.g$b$a$a.run(Unknown Source:37)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: Do you have any code that contains a `Runnable` that throws an exception in the `run()` method? Your code is obfuscated, so you might want to make a release/signed build without obfuscation and see if that also crashes. If so, you will have a more usable stacktrace.

Comment: Hi Gurpreet. If want to de-obfuscate your stack trace. The mapping file is in build/outputs/mapping. Run the tool: Android/Sdk/tools/proguard/bin/proguardgui.bat. Select 'retrace' and add your mapping file and crash stack. Regards.

Comment: The obfuscation of Models was causing this error. So I have added models in the proguard file so that they are prevented from obfuscation. Thank you guys.